# JSF 1.2 h:commandLink not working, mojarra is not defined

Tags: java, jsf, navigation, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I got a problem with JSF 1.2 on websphere 7.
I'm trying to implement a navigation with JSF.
I'm also using RichFaces.

In the console of the browser I got this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: mojarra is not defined`

I have seen other with this problem and they solved it with adding `<h:head>` but this didn't work for me.

Thank you for helping

My navigation.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<body>
<ui:composition>
    <h:form>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div id="navigation" class="navigation">
            <div class="level0">
               <h:commandLink action="#{navigation.toHome}" value="#{messages.elsi_dg_navigation_home}" />
            </div>
            <div class="level0">
                <h:commandLink action="#{navigation.toHistory}" value="#{messages.elsi_dg_navigation_history}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition></body></html>
```

The NavigationBean.java

```
@Controller("navigation")
@Scope("session")
@ManagedBean
public class NavigationBean {

private String lastSite = "home";


public String toHome() {
    return this.processOutcome("home");
}

public String toHistory() {
    return this.processOutcome("history");
}

public String toCurrentPage() {
    return this.lastSite;
}

private String processOutcome(String outcome) {
    this.lastSite = outcome;
    return outcome;
}
}
```

HTML output:

```
<div id="navigation" class="navigation">
<form id="j_id19" name="j_id19" method="post" action="/elsi-dg/xhtml/home.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id19" value="j_id19">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div id="navigation" class="navigation">
        <div class="level0"><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_id19'),{'j_id19:j_id21':'j_id19:j_id21'},'');return false">Home</a></div>
        <div class="level0"><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_id19'),{'j_id19:j_id23':'j_id19:j_id23'},'');return false">History</a></div>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="3428583661652779493:-8865896015881316410" autocomplete="off">
</form>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

`<a4j:commandLink>` works without problems..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with the tag **ui:compostion**

```
 <ui:composition template="./template/template.xhtml">
```

It normally needs a **template file**.

Are you using one? 
If you aren't, try to remove the `<ui:composition>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I'm using a template file I forgot to mentoin that in my question. Im currently using a4j as workaround this works without problems